Reshaping wide data
I'm grabbing some price data via bloomberg (xbbg) in python and because of the way it's pulling, I end up with something like the below (first table). How can I convert this to long data, something like in the second table? This seems like a simple conversion from wide data to long data, but for some reason I can't quite seem to put it in the correct format. Also, this is just a sample, in the real file, there are more dates and more tickers.
Raw table:



blp
2023-10-24
2023-12-11
2023-10-26
2024-01-05
2024-01-09
2024-01-17
2024-01-17




DOV US Equity
132.33





131


PRU US Equity

101.43


98




RSG US Equity


146.02






CVS US Equity



81.42





LEN US Equity




148.16




OKE US Equity





69.06




Desired Output:



blp
date
price




DOV US Equity
10/24/2023
132.33


PRU US Equity
12/11/2023
101.43


RSG US Equity
10/26/2023
146.02


CVS US Equity
1/5/2024
81.42


LEN US Equity
1/9/2024
148.16


OKE US Equity
1/17/2024
69.06


DOV US Equity
1/17/2024
131


PRU US Equity
1/9/2024
98



EDIT:
ticker_list = fin['instrument'].reset_index(drop=True)
date_list = fin['declared_date'].reset_index(drop=True)

dfs = []
for i in range(len(date_list)):
     df = blp.bdh(tickers=ticker_list[i], flds= 
 ['PX_LAST'],start_date=date_list[i], end_date=date_list[i]) 
dfs.append(df)
df_final = pd.concat(dfs,axis=0)
df_final

df_final_transpose= df_final.transpose()
df_final_transpose.index.names = ['blp', 'Field']
df_final_transpose=df_final_transpose.droplevel('Field')
df_final_transpose=df_final_transpose.reset_index(drop=False)

where fin is a separate dataframe that includes columns for tickers (Instrument) and date (declared_date). df_final is the raw dataframe coming directly from the bloomberg pull and df_final_transpose is my attempt to convert the bloomberg pull into the desired table format.

I don't know what you mean by "raw table".  How, exactly, are you fetching the data?  What do you get back?  Surely it's an object or list of values.  Show us your code.

Just adjusted the question to include code snippet. thanks for taking a look.

You can't just blithely concatenate all of these together.  I believe you're going to need to transfer the data from the df in your loop into one master df, a line at a time.

Why is there a duplicate 2024-01-17 column? I don't think that's possible with concat along axis=0, but I might be wrong.

Have you read the user guide? Reshaping and pivot tables

Hi wjandrea, that's just a typo. Might have duped a column when i was trying to create my sample to post

I'm not familiar with xbbg, but it looks like it's not "the way it's pulling", it's how you're combining dfs. If you reshaped them before concat, you wouldn't end up with all those blank cells.

df.set_index('blp').stack().rename_axis(columns='date').reset_index(name='price')

Yes, wjandrea, I just realized that. After doing some formatting after the df line and befor e appending, I can format as I need. I figured it out, thanks so much for the help

You can do that:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'blp': ['DOV US Equity', 'PRU US Equity', 'RSG US Equity', 'CVS US Equity', 'LEN US Equity', 'OKE US Equity'],
    '2023-10-24': [132.33, None, None, None, None, None],
    '2023-12-11': [None, 101.43, None, None, None, None],
    '2023-10-26': [None, None, 146.02, None, None, None],
    '2024-01-05': [None, None, None, 81.42, None, None],
    '2024-01-09': [None, 98, None, None, 148.16, None],
    '2024-01-17': [131, None, None, None, None, 69.06],
}

df_before = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df_after = df_before.melt(id_vars='blp', var_name='date', value_name='price').dropna(subset='price')

df_before:
| blp           |   2023-10-24 |   2023-12-11 |   2023-10-26 |   2024-01-05 |   2024-01-09 |   2024-01-17 |
|:--------------|-------------:|-------------:|-------------:|-------------:|-------------:|-------------:|
| DOV US Equity |       132.33 |       nan    |       nan    |       nan    |       nan    |       131    |
| PRU US Equity |       nan    |       101.43 |       nan    |       nan    |        98    |       nan    |
| RSG US Equity |       nan    |       nan    |       146.02 |       nan    |       nan    |       nan    |
| CVS US Equity |       nan    |       nan    |       nan    |        81.42 |       nan    |       nan    |
| LEN US Equity |       nan    |       nan    |       nan    |       nan    |       148.16 |       nan    |
| OKE US Equity |       nan    |       nan    |       nan    |       nan    |       nan    |        69.06 |

df_after:
| blp           | date       |   price |
|:--------------|:-----------|--------:|
| DOV US Equity | 2023-10-24 |  132.33 |
| PRU US Equity | 2023-12-11 |  101.43 |
| RSG US Equity | 2023-10-26 |  146.02 |
| CVS US Equity | 2024-01-05 |   81.42 |
| PRU US Equity | 2024-01-09 |   98    |
| LEN US Equity | 2024-01-09 |  148.16 |
| DOV US Equity | 2024-01-17 |  131    |
| OKE US Equity | 2024-01-17 |   69.06 |

